# How to get average difference of timestamp in hive

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, hiveql, bigdata

I have this table below which contains two column

```
hive> select * from hivetable;

a 2016-09-16T03:01:12.367782Z
b 2016-09-16T03:01:12.300514Z
c 2016-09-16T03:01:12.241532Z
a 2016-09-16T03:01:12.138016Z
c 2016-09-16T03:01:12.136986Z
b 2016-09-16T03:01:10.512201Z
c 2016-09-16T03:01:12.235671Z

Time taken: 0.457 seconds, Fetched: 7 row(s)
```

and now I want to find the unique value from first column and the timestamp difference or I should say average timestamp difference in case there are more than 2 records as in case of c. so in my case the output should be like

```
a  1 day 5 hr 30 min 20 sec
b  5 sec
c  30 minutes
```

Note: it is just a sample output and not the actual output

Is it possible to get this output or any similar one in hive?

Comment: remove the tag not related to your query ..

Comment: I have made the change.

Comment: see lag() or lead() function in https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use a window function to select the previous row in the grouping. I don't believe it can be compressed into just one query.

```
select 
 id,
 avg(DATEDIFF(time, prev_time)) as avg_time_diff_days
from (
   select id,
   time,
   LAG(time, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY id, time ORDER BY time ASC)) as prev_time
   from table
) intervals
group by id;
```